# Работа с БД (wpf)

Tags: c#, wpf

Как тут работать с БД? Там файл создается .sdf, а как без него, что бы только был один .exe-шник и как запросы слать покажите, а лучше ссылку на ману.

Comment: Для начала, WPF -- это графический фреймворк. А на вопрос, как работать с базами данных, существуют ответы в книжках. Прочитайте их, и приходите с конкретными вопросами.

Answer (score 2):

А еще лучше бы ты сам пошел и почитал что-нибудь о этой теме в гугле.

[Методичка по работе с БД в C#](http://narod.ru/disk/54749680001.b3cc88eaf1c31602e29353fb488799ab/Sharp.pdf.html) - очень полезная вещь.

Answer (score 0):

Конечно лучше почитать об этом в книжке... 
Вот тут найдешь несколько [подходящих книжек по си шарпу и бд](http://cesharp.ru/urok1.html)